# How to make a drop down menu the same width as the trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an image this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

This is how i'm starting out the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var userWidth = $('#userOptions.width()');
            var menuWidth = $('#userOptionsMenu.width()')


            function menuMatch() {
                if(menuWidth < userWidth) {
                    menuWidth = userWidth;
                }
            }

            menuMatch();

        });
```

Here is an image with the ID's:

[image]

In function menuMatch() i'm not sure how to write in JS how to make something equal in width to the element it's currently narrower than.

Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Here's a link to a codepen  http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/cGwbC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling the jQuery width property incorrectly.  Change this:

```
var userWidth = $('#userOptions.width()');
var menuWidth = $('#userOptionsMenu.width()')
```

to this:

```
var userWidth = $('#userOptions').width();
var menuWidth = $('#userOptionsMenu').width();
```

This will get you the width you need to set.  Then to correctly apply the css, you need to do this:

```
function menuMatch() {
    if(menuWidth < userWidth) {
        $("#userOptionsMenu").css("width", userWidth + "px");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed like a really solid solution for some reason it doesn't work for me. I've included a codepen here with the bare minimum to show thats' true http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/cGwbC

Comment: Actually your code also worked but I can't figure out why it doesn't on my project. The site i'm working on is huge and i'm only working on one part. I'm wondering if i'm not ordering my scripts properly; any debugging tips? http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/cGwbC?editors=001

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong I was chaining the .css method on my variable menuWidth which I can't do because it's pulling a numerical value, that's why i see now why you opted to call the actual element $('#userOptionsMenu'). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1) You included `width()` within the selector. The function should be called after the selector.

2) You need to set the width using `width()` as a selector, instead of just modifying the variable you set `$('#userOptionsMenu').width()` equal to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var userWidth = $('#userOptions').width();     // These should be
        var menuWidth = $('#userOptionsMenu').width(); // outside of the quotes

        function menuMatch() {
            if(menuWidth < userWidth) {
                $('#userOptionsMenu').width(userWidth); // Change the value of
            }                                           // the width using
        }                                               // width() as a setter.

        menuMatch();
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this answer responsive?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas yeah I got lazy and only used comments. updated

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ thanks for the guidance that's helpful. Unfortunately that didn't work and i'm asking myself why that wouldn't work, it seems logical.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Actually your code does work on this codepen http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/cGwbC?editors=001  now i have to figure out why it doesn't work on my code, I'm wondering if it has to do with script order. The site is huge and i'm only working on a certain piece of it. Any tips for debugging? Thanks.